# Checking Conditions In Three Tables and Printing Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had Table `'tblPacks','tblBlisters','tblShippers'` .Now I want a stored procedure that User Will Send `T_id,BatchNumber` Now I have To check whether the `T_id And BatchNumber` Exists in those tables.If `T_ID,BatchNumber` exists in `'tblPacks'` and not exists in `'tblBlisters' and 'tblshippers'` It should `print T_ID,BatchNumber and names of the table where those two columns present
Example:-

'tblPacks' Table Structure

```
 T_ID  BatchNumber PackId Status 
----   ----------  ------  -----
 1       101        ABC001  0
```

'tblBlisters' Table Structure

```
T_ID  BatchNumber BlisterId Status 
----   ----------  ------  -----
 1       101       PAC001  0
```

'tblShippers' Table Structure

```
T_ID  BatchNumber ShipperId Status 
----   ----------  ------  ----- 
  1       101        KBC001  0
```

For example,If User Gives `T_id,BatchNumber` as 1,101 Now As Per Condition I should print T_ID as '1' BatchNumber as '101; and should print `'tblPacks,tblBlisters,tblShippers'` because `T_id and BatchNumber` exists in three tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query unions together the three tables and then aggregates over ID and batch number to produce a CSV list of tables for those tables where the ID and batch number are present.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT T_ID, BatchNumber, 'tblPacks' AS label
    FROM tblPacks
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T_ID, BatchNumber, 'tblBlisters'
    FROM tblBlisters
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T_ID, BatchNumber, 'tblShippers'
    FROM tblShippers
)

SELECT t1.T_ID,
       t1.BatchNumber,
       STUFF((SELECT N', ' + t2.label
              FROM cte AS t2
              WHERE t1.T_ID = t2.T_ID AND
                    t1.BatchNumber = t2.BatchNumber
              ORDER BY t2.label
              FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'') AS tables_present
FROM cte t1
WHERE t1.T_ID = 1 AND
      t1.BatchNumber = 101
GROUP BY t1.T_ID,
         t1.BatchNumber
```

Comment: Here I Have to know T_ID and BatchNumber Exists in which tables whether one or two or three just printing 1 1 1 won't help me How can I do that Help me @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @saibharath I don't see any problem with my query.  Can you try to make it work?  Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Thanks for finding that typo :-)

Comment: Thank You So Much  @ Tim Biegeleisen